# How to prevent direct URL calls but allow from my Android app

Tags: php, android

So, I've got an Android app that loads data from a database, before doing anything the user must log in. In my app, the login form is very simple: username/email & password. Then a request is made https://example.com/login/ with the form values as POST parameters. My question is: how do I prevent from anyone just directly accessing that URL and making their custom POST requests but allow the requests from my app?

Comment: Are you trying to limit other POST requests because you're worried about people brute forcing logins? If so, throttling incorrect login attempts is going to be infinitely more effective than trying to lock down the source of login attempts to only "legitimate" sources.

Comment: I will also do that, but I want to prevent others from direct-accessing the URL too.

Comment: You can make it harder for others to find the address of the server but you should not really worry about others figuring out your server address. If you have a secure authentication in place then it should not be a problem at all.

Comment: you can't prevent people from doing it. What you can is only making that harder to do. For example, you can use something like one more parameter that will only your android app know. So if the parameter is missing or incorrect - it means that it is not your app request.

Answer (score -2):

Best way to do it is by using **token**. 
Just use a Token for checking validation of an API call. 
And return the appropriate response only if it matches the value of Token

Comment: token is generated on successful login request. How do you generate the token for validating the login request itself?

Comment: why do you think that it is best way? Any proof?